# Saving and updating Object array in a file in internal storage Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, file-handling, android-internal-storage

I am new to android. I want to save an object containing two strings in a file in the internal storage of the phone. It can be like an array of pairs of strings.

I want to read an array of objects from the file. I also want to update this file(add and delete entries from the app itself)
Attaching my class file

```
package com.example.ratingfinder.model

class Friend (val platformName: String, val HandleName: String){
    //some member functions
}
```